# Jewish communities west of London

Tags: product-recommendation, geography, chutz-laaretz, english, communities

My employer has asked me to move to as close as possible to their main office in [Bramley, Hampshire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bramley,_Hampshire) (between Basingstoke and Reading). However, I do wish to live in a place with some orthodox Jewish presence, among other reasons, because I have two pre-school children.

Living in Greater London is not an option as the commute would be too much.

What orthodox communities exist in the area, or between there and London?

Comment: There's [an Orthodox synagogue in Reading](http://www.rhc.org.uk/), but I don't see a Jewish primary school there.

Comment: @msh210 Yes, I'm considering that. I do know how to search online. I was hoping to discover any places that may not have an (easily findable) online presence.

Comment: You might want to look through the list of United Synagogue communities at http://www.theus.org.uk/communities, which you can filter by "Area," and at the broader ["List of Jewish communities in the United Kingdom"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jewish_communities_in_the_United_Kingdom) on Wikipedia, which includes both Orthodox and non-Orthodox communities. The latter has for Reading the synagogue that @msh210 mentioned as well as the [Jewish Community of Berkshire](http://www.jcob.org/).

Comment: I would think that Reading or Oxford are about the only possibilities. I doubt if either have much in terms of formal Jewish education though. Maybe Bournemouth, but it's a long distance for a commute.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66786